# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.initializers' has no attribute 'TruncatedNormal'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nlp, transformer-model, sentence-transformers

I get the following error when I try to import sentence_transformers in `python 3.6.7` and `tensorflow==2.3.0`. Can someone please help me with this? Seems like it's a bug in the transformers package.

```
import sentence_transformers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentence_transformers/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .datasets import SentencesDataset, SentenceLabelDataset, ParallelSentencesDataset
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentence_transformers/datasets/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .sampler import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentence_transformers/datasets/sampler/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .LabelSampler import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentence_transformers/datasets/sampler/LabelSampler.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ...datasets import SentenceLabelDataset
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentence_transformers/datasets/SentenceLabelDataset.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .. import SentenceTransformer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 11, in <module>
    import transformers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    from .pipelines import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/pipelines.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .modeling_tf_auto import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_auto.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .modeling_tf_albert import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_albert.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .modeling_tf_utils import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_utils.py", line 943, in <module>
    def get_initializer(initializer_range: float = 0.02) -> tf.initializers.TruncatedNormal:
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/module_wrapper.py", line 194, in __getattr__
    attr = getattr(self._tfmw_wrapped_module, name)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.initializers' has no attribute 'TruncatedNormal'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
initializer = tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal()
```

or

```
initializer = tf.compat.v1.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal()
```

In tensorflow2.3.0,you can't find 'TruncatedNormal' in  module 'tensorflow._api.v1.initializers'.
Maybe this version has removed this attribute.